# Creating a view that contains all records from one table, that match the comma separated field content in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two tables au_postcodes and groups.

1. Table *groups* contains a field called **PostCodeFootPrint**
   that contains the postcode set making up the footprint.
2. Table *au_postcodes* contains a field called **poa_code** that
   contains a single postcode.

The records in *groups*.**PostCodeFootPrint** look like:

| PostCodeFootPrint |
| --- |
| 2529,2530,2533,2534,2535,2536,2537,2538,2539,2540,2541,2575,2576,2577,2580 |
| 2640 |
| 3844 |
| 2063, 2064, 2065, 2066, 2067, 2068, 2069, 2070, 2071, 2072, 2073, 2074, 2075, 2076, 2077, 2079, 2080, 2081, 2082, 2083, 2119, 2120, 2126, 2158, 2159 |
| 2848, 2849, 2850, 2852 |

Some records have only one postcode, some have multiple separated by a "," or ", " (comma and space).

The records in *au_postcode*.**poa_code** look like:

| poa_code |
| --- |
| 2090 |
| 2092 |
| 2093 |
| 829 |
| 830 |
| 836 |
| 2080 |
| 2081 |

Single postcode (always).

The objective is to:

Get all records from au_postcode, where the poa_code appears in *groups*.**PostCodeFootPrint* into a view.

I tried:

```
SELECT
    au_postcodes.poa_code, 
    groups."NameOfGroup"
FROM
    groups,
    au_postcodes
WHERE
    groups."PostcodeFootprint" LIKE '%au_postcodes.poa_code%'
```

But no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this.  Take a look at this fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=739592ef262231722d783670b46bd7fa

Where I form a regex from the poa_code and the word boundary (to avoid partial matches) and compare that to the PostCodeFootPrint.

```
select p.poa_code, g.PostCodeFootPrint
from groups g
join au_postcode p 
on g.PostCodeFootPrint ~ concat('\y', p.poa_code, '\y')
```

Depending on your data, this may be performant enough.  I also believe that in postGres you have access to the array data type, and so it might be better to store the post code lists as arrays.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ae24683952cb2b0f3832113375fbb55b

Here I stored the post code lists as arrays, then used ANY to join with.

```
select p.poa_code, g.PostCodeFootPrint
from groups g
join au_postcode p 
on p.poa_code = any(g.PostCodeFootPrint);
```

In these two fiddles I use explain to show the cost of the queries, and while the array solution is more expensive, I imagine it might be easier to maintain.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7f16676825e10625b90eb62e8018d78e

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e96e0fc463f46a7c467421b47683f42f

I changed the underlying data type to integer in this fiddle, expecting it to reduce the cost, but it didn't, which seems strange to me.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=521d6a7d0eb4c45471263214186e537e

It is possible to reduce the query cost with the # operator (see the last query here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=edc9b07e9b22ee72f856e9234dbec4ba):

```
select p.poa_code, g.PostCodeFootPrint
from groups g
join au_postcode p 
on (g.PostCodeFootPrint # p.poa_code) > 0;
```

but it is still more expensive than the regex.  However, I think you can probably rearrange the way the tables are set up and radically change performance.  See the first and second queries in the fiddle, where I take each post code in the footprint and insert it as a row in a table, along with an identifier for the group it was in:

```
select p.poa_code, g.which
from groups2 g
join au_postcode p 
on g.footprint = p.poa_code;
```

The explain plan for this indicates that query cost drops significantly (from 60752.50 to 517.20, or two orders of magnitude) and the execution times go from 0.487 to 0.070.  So it might be worth looking into changing the table structure.

Comment: Chris
THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: But I do think there are probably better ways to set up the data to improve the performance.  I think that is quite a high cost for such a simple query.  I just don't know enough about your use case to suggest something to you.  What are the lists used for?

Comment: @help4bis: I made an edit suggesting a different structure that might be more performant.

Comment: If this helped you, please consider upvoting or accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the values of `PostCodeFootPrint` are separated by a common character, you can easily create an array out of it. From there use `unnest` to convert the array elements to records, and then join then with `au_postcode`:

```
SELECT * FROM au_postcode au
JOIN (SELECT trim(unnest(string_to_array(PostCodeFootPrint,','))) 
      FROM groups) fp (PostCodeFootPrint) ON fp.PostCodeFootPrint = au.poa_code;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=532c0f49ec37dd8d07ab52096c095394)

Comment: Can you tell me why converting the text to an array then unnesting and then trimming the value is so much more performant than simply storing the values in table as arrays in the first place?

Comment: Hey @ChrisStrickland , it is definitely not faster - and I hope my post didn't give this impression. The OP's data model is imho a pretty bad one, and depending on the "array" sizes and number of records there is not much one can do to speed things up. But yes, storing the converted arrays into a column (and properly indexing it!) will definitely improve query time. +1 for reaching out!

Comment: I see that I was looking at the query cost and not the execution time.  The cost is quite low when compared to some of my other fiddles (the exception being where I redid the structure so that the footprint was stored as rows in a table), but the execution time is high.  I didn't realize that cost and time could be so disconnected.